# vNext build System.Activities.statements.writeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am tasked with writing a file to include with the source code after a build.

With xaml, I used System.Activities.statements.writeline so that I could bundle everything in the build template. I know that I can use PowerShell or a batch to achieve what I need however I do not have access to the build box and I do not want to force my developers to include files not associated with the application in source control.

Is there a way to create a file and add text with a build task and not be dependent on anything other than the build tasks?

Thanks,

Comment: Do you solve this issue with Inline Script of PowerShell task or custom build task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PowerShell task and choose "Inline Script". You can then write any script you want in there.

However, I'd make the case that it **should** be source controlled. Files required for your build and deployment processes *are* part of the application, if you think in terms of DevOps.

Answer (score 0):

You can custom build task and do that in the build task script directly.

[Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task)